# Alternative to IE 10 Conditional Comments to center positioned div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I use this code to center absolutely positioned div

```
.class{
   width: 10px; 
   height:10px; 
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   top:0; 
   bottom:0; 
   margin:auto
}
```

This is not working in IE 10 and lower versions, but I dont want to change this code as it's comfortable for all other browsers and devices.

I know that Conditional comments are not working in IE 10 too, so how can I solve this issue there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have besides those options mentioned above:

Calculated Padding + Width:

```
.container {
  padding:5%;
}
.container .center{
  width:90%;
  height:90%;
  display:block;
}
```

Or if you only need it to be horizontally centered:

```
.centered {
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

But if you still aren't getting any results to work, then you may have malformed HTML.  When internet explorer finds bad HTML or a meta tag expressing a specific version to emulate, it will and then newer features don't work.  I recreated your style on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrL0p925/1/) and it worked for me even on internet explorer 8 (Although 7 did fail).  Otherwise you may not be putting a position value on the CSS of the parent element if it is apearing out of place.

Comment: Thanks man,you gave me an idea, I checked the same in other PC and it works, before I checked it in new IE 11 and used emulation to change its version.Not sure why, but I think the issue is connected to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect by JavaScript if the browser is **IE10**. If it is you can add a special class in the page body or in any html element you want.

**JS**

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 10") > -1) {
    document.body.classList.add("ie10");
}
```

**CSS**

```
.ie10 {
    ...
}
```